# Does FancyBox have a minimum height?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've run into an issue with FancyBox. I upgraded to V2 and now my FancyBoxes appear to be `200px`. I used to be able to have FBs that were only `50 - 60 px` tall because there was only one line of text. What happened?

I've tried (separately, not at the same time) adding the following to the setup for the FB:

```
autoSize: true
height: 60
height: '60px'
autoDimensions: true
```

Ideas?

Comment: The ones that would know the best are the developers behind Fancybox, http://fancybox.net/support. On this page there is a link to a google group as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new version of Fancybox (v2.x) has now these options with these default values:

```
minWidth: 200,
minHeight: 200,
```

but you can modify them as your convenience within your custom script

Check the documentation [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox#docs)

Comment: Yes I know it has those settings, which are great if I wanted my boxes BIGGER than 200x200. But it seems that there is a bug because no matter what I did with those settings, it didn't affect it. I ended up actually editing the js source and changing the default 200px to 50px so that I could do a very small box with just a single line of text.

Comment: For a single line of text you may use minWidth: 'auto', minHeight: 'auto' ... if that not works my guess you have some syntax error or something else. Editing the js file should be the very last resource.

Comment: @AndrewChristensen: You really should accept this answer, in my opinion.  You can always set minWidth: 50px to REDUCE the minimum width, you know.